# Action not triggered in seam

Tags: jboss, seam

In my pages.xml file, I have this instruction:

```
 <page view-id="*" action="#{guestLogin.logIn}" />
```

but it never gets triggered! My guestLogin.login looks like this:

```
import org.jboss.seam.ScopeType;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.*;

@Name("guestLogin")
@Scope(ScopeType.STATELESS)
public class GuestLogin {
    public void logIn()
       {
          throw new RuntimeException();
       }
}
```

However, as I click thru the app, I see no RunTimeException, nor any other kind of exception, in the app. When I break the pages.xml file, the app doesn't deploy right, so it can't be that I'm editing the wrong file.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same logic in one of my projects, there are a couple of subtle differences, I don't know for sure if they are pertinent, but give them a try!

```
<page view-id="/*" action="#{countrySelection.checkCountry()}" />
```

differences:

1) I have `view-id="/*"` instead of `view-id="*"`

2) I have the parenthesis added to the method